# Why is nancy complaining about a missing reference for System?

Tags: nancy

I added a X509Certificate2 property to my model, and now my razor view won't compile. The exact error message is...

> [CS0012] Line: 84 Column: 18 - Le type
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2' est
>   défini dans un assembly qui n'est pas référencé. Vous devez
>   ajouter une référence à  l'assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. (show)

Sorry for my french, but you get the idea.

X509Certificate2 is defined in System.dll, and I have a reference for System in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok silly me again. References needed by razor need to be explicitly listed in web.config. It's not asking for a project reference. This is all explained [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine), in the "Configuring Razor" section.